# Wordpress check if is tag page

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a function like `is_single` for the tag page? something `like is_tag`?I need to do an if statement and something like this will be usefull.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`is_tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tag)

Imagine that.

Comment: @Uffo, thanks! (I know, right? Sometimes it's just too easy.)

Comment: I will NOT downvote you but I think someone do it because URL is invalid (that's happen when you answer with only a link)